# ImageMosaic plugin for DEM rasters on Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, dem, image-mosaic

I'm using 30m DEM rasters from the NRCS Data Gateway. I use image mosaic to merge them. But when i preview i see black gaps between rasters.

[image]

Coverager Parameters:

[image]

How can i remove that black gaps?

Comment: Could be anything. Are you using the latest version of GeoServer? Did you check the files are actually properly aligned? Are you reprojecting the data or displaying it in its native CRS? Does it show fine if you load the datasets separately and do a GetMap with all the resulting layers?

Comment: Yes i use latest version, 2.13.2. When i open files in arcmap, they look aligned. I reprojected the data but i also tried with its native CRS too, same problem. I don't know how to GetMap? @AndreaAime